# SQL select all but exlude results when datetime is between midnight and 6am

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

I have a basic problem with an SQL query and I can't find the solution. I have a table where the first column is a epoch timestamp and a new entry is saved every 15min, and I want to select all the entires between two dates. Let's say a month. That's easy, I just use a regular query like

`SELECT * from MyTable where date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-04-01 00:00:00") and date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-05-01 00:00:00");` .

But now let's say I want to select all my entries for the whole month just like before, but EXCLUDING the entries that have been added between midnight and 6am. How could I do that ? I can't imagine any simple and straight forward way to do it. My query is executed in a Perl script so I could do a loop that would query all the results for anything above 6am every day but it would be "ugly".

Thanks !

(Yes i know I named my column date and date is actually a function, it's bad i won't dit it again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thank you for those you responded, I used your exemples and managed to make em work with my table and my data. Here's the final request :

```
SELECT * from My Table
where time(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) > '06:00:00'
and `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-05-01 00:00:00") 
and `date` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-05-02 00:00:00");
```

Basically the first answer was correct with only the fact that "where time..." needed the function FROM_UNIXTIME to work too.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `time()` function to extract the time part of the datetime column and then check that the time is after 6 am.

```
SELECT * from MyTable 
where time(`date`) > '06:00:00'
and `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-04-01 00:00:00") 
and `date` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-05-01 00:00:00")
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd637/4)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, strange since it works on your fiddle. I get a lot of warnings :
mysql> select * from MyTable WHERE time(date) > '06:00:00' and date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-05-05 00:00:00") and date < ("2015-05-06 00:00:00") GROUP BY eqt;
Empty set, 65535 warnings (0.06 sec)

Comment: has to be `date` not date. date is a mysql function, you need to use ` to say "use the date field, not the function"

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu No, MySQL permits the use of date as an identifier without quotes even though it is a keyword for backward compatibility reasons. It would be good practice to quote it though (or use another name altogether).

Comment: @user2407268 Does the date comparison with the unix_timestamp work? Maybe you need to use a date literal instead? See this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd637/11

Answer (score 1):

what about something like:

```
SELECT * 
from MyTable 
where mydate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-04-01 00:00:00") 
    and date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-05-01 00:00:00")
    and HOUR(time(mydate)) >= 6;
```

Comment: I had it backwards a second ago, i was including *only* 0-6 rather than excluding 0-6 - sorry about that.  The above would be more accurate, though it will actually include 6am on the dot.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because in reality my table is called date and note mydate, so since date is a function it does weird things with the HOUR(time thing. I'll try to quote date to indicate it's a column and i'll tell you how it goes